# java.text.ParseException issue with hibernate after update

Tags: hibernate, date-formatting

i have an action class where i do a date format converting using  simpledateformat,my problem is the  java.text.ParseException that's raised  when i select the list to use it in my getjson  response after a succesfull  update against a class object(except date Field) using hibernate.
when i also update the date field in my class using hibernate,nothing occurs.

here's the code that i use :

```
Date d;
  String newformat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
  String oldformat= "yyyy-MM-dd";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf;
this.mapjourferiejson=new LinkedHashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
  List<String> infostring=new  ArrayList<String>();
//function doing the hql request
  List<JourFerie> listjourferiejson=jourferieservice.findAll();
try
  {
  for(JourFerie jourferie:listjourferiejson)
  {
     sdf= new SimpleDateFormat(oldformat);
     System.out.println("la date est : "+jourferie.getDate());
     d = sdf.parse(jourferie.getDate().toString());
     sdf.applyPattern(newformat);
     infostring.add(sdf.format(d));
     infostring.add(jourferie.getNombrejours().toString());
     infostring.add(jourferie.getOccasion()); 
     this.mapjourferiejson.put(jourferie.getJourferieId(), infostring);
     //je vide le set pour un autre reutilisation
     infostring=new  ArrayList<String>();
  }  
  }catch(ParseException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("erreur dans le parsing");

  }
```

here's the log of my all parsed dates :
the date  : 2012-01-01
the date : 2012-01-01
the date : 2012-01-02
the date : 2012-01-02
the date : 2012-01-03
the date : Wed Jan 11 00:00:00 WAT 2012

Comment: what type does this return `jourferie.getDate()` ?   I presume the line throwing exception is the sdf.parse() ?

Comment: jourferie.getDate() return java.util.Date object,the problem is not  in the getter but when i fetch data after an update using hibernate on mysql database

Comment: MySQL will happily insert dates like `0000-00-00 00:00:00.0000` (that the rest of the universe does not like) what you really need to do is show us the data from MySQL command line query tool, before and after, hibernate operates on the record.

Comment: all my dates before and after hibernate operates are in the format yyyy-MM-dd that's why i use oldformat for in the code,so i think that hibernate doesn't fetch all the data from database but only it uses the objects existing from his cache.the exception doesn't occur when i update the date of my class using hibernate,but only when i update other fields except the date object of the class that i want to change, do you have any clue for this issue.

Comment: thank you for the hint,i have used d = jourferie.getDate(); directly and it worked for me.now i undestand why it gives me the java vm locale. Thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I move to answer to make some points (try to make some yourself sometime).

```
d = sdf.parse(jourferie.getDate().toString());
// is doing type conversion like Date => String => Date
// why ? why not d = jourferie.getDate(); ?
```

But getDate() is a Java method and the string format uses the Java VM locale. This format has nothing to do with the MySQL format in SQL.